# How to check whether a glass is connected with phone using Bluetooth?

Tags: android, google-glass

I am working on call functionality on Google Glass.
If the glass is connected to phone then the functionality works but if the glass is not connected then the app goes in a endless loop and needs a restart.

Is there any way by which I can check whether it is connected to any device or not.

I tried `BroadcastReceiver` for checking the connectivity but none worked.
Please help on it.